# Monkeypatching C stdin from Python

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

Is there any way of monkeypatching the C version of stdin in Python?

I’m attempting to write unit tests (pytest) for a Python module written in C. One of the functions in the library tries to read a value from stdin. I have no idea how to get around this. If it were a Python function, I’d monkey patch sys.stdin. But that doesn’t work here.

If forced to, I can start a new process with redirected standard input, but I’m hoping to avoid that.

I didn’t write the module. I’m just testing it. . . .

Comment: It seems like if it’s written in C and you’re testing it from Python, it’s an integration test, not a unit test.  If it were me I’d go into the C code and write tests (or at least test helpers) there.

Comment: @Samwise: I disagree. What matters for unit testing is the interface and behavior a function presents to callers, not what language it happens to be implemented in. NumPy's unit tests are written in Python, as are the unit tests for the C parts of the Python standard library. (And bypassing `sys.stdin` isn't specific to C code, even if it's more common in C.)

Comment: @FrankYellin: You may not have written this code, but can you change it? It probably doesn't *have* to bypass `sys.stdin`, and bypassing `sys.stdin` is a usability problem for use cases beyond just testing.

Comment: I think you could open a pipe and then connect `stdin` to it with `os.dup2(0, pipe_fd);`

Comment: (Gotta be really careful about making sure you don't deadlock yourself with that pipe, though - a pipe's buffer is finite, so you can't always just write all the test data up front. It gets even worse if the function under test reads stdin in a way that doesn't release the GIL - then using a writer thread may not be enough, and you may need an entire separate writer process.)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? For questions like this, specifics matter, and we'll be able to provide better answers if we can see the actual problem (e.g., @Barmar's suggestion is probably the way to go, but you haven't provided us with enough context for us to test it).